# how to see variable values in locals and expressions of qt

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt5

I have qt 5.12.12 on Ubuntu with GCC as compiler and GDB as debugger. When debug hit on a breakpoint, almost all of my variables are shown as memory addresses in locals and expressions(only int values are shown correctly).

locals :
[locals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHfu5.png)

expressions :
[expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrlRa.png)

I tried some solutions without any success:

*Use tooltips in main editor while debugging* is checked
[tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwdeG.png)

*Load system GDB pretty printers* is unchecked
[pretty printers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAbIA.png)

*Use Debugging Helpers* is checked
[Debugging Helpers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Q78.png)

Also expanding a QString value as an example doesn't go anywhere:
[expanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPdPO.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the the view by clicking the the arrow on the left besides the variable name to show what is stored at a the displayed memory address.

On this website you can find more about displaying locals and also about adding and removing expression evaluators.

https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-locals-view.html

Comment: did you see last image? it is expanded with no value shown.